# manage proxy based on destination on linux

Tags: linux, docker, proxy, privoxy

i have a socks5 proxy on local network. (think 192.168.1.5:9150)
i need another proxyserver on my local network that serve socks5 proxy (192.168.1.10)
i want some functionality like switch omega everybody can connect to 192.168.1.10 some request pass from 192.168.5 other go to the gateway. i try privoxy but i can't serve that socks5 only https and http proxy.

if anybody open bing.com --> 192.168.10 --> internet

if anybody open google.com --> 192.168.10 --> 192.168.1.5 --> internet

i have some container that send some request to the internet. they serve in local network or talk to each other, etc. some apps inside them not support proxy inside application or make difficult to handle all of them individualy. one of container give me socks5 or http proxy. but i don't pass internal request or all outside request pass proxy(some request should not pass proxy at all in any situation). how should i serve that proxy.pac in specific proxy and later i just maintain that proxy.pac? is there any option give me a nice webui too? or easly update that when i change that pac file?

Comment: That sounds like you're going to need something similar to a `proxy.pac` definition. You then get into all sorts of fun with `wpad.{your.domain}` and the like. Also consider what should happen if somebody uses the "wrong" proxy - what will happen? Could you rethink your approach to have the single proxy to the right thing according to the destination it's being asked to reach?